# Javascript file reader does not get stored in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to upload multiple images. So I read that I can generate a temporary url and send them with ajax.

The idea is push the url created with filereader into an array and the send with ajax but the url's are not pushed properly. When I see the result I got like an empty array:

[image]

But if I click the arrow I can see the url's inside

[image]

But them seems Inaccessible.

This is my code:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var filesToUpload = document.getElementById("myFile");
        var files = filesToUpload.files;
        var fd = new FormData();
        var arr = [];

        if (FileReader && files && files.length) {

            for (i=0; i< files.length; i++){


                (function(file) {

                    var name = file.name;
                    var fr = new FileReader();  


                    fr.onload = function () {

                            arr.push(fr.result);

                    }

                    fr.readAsDataURL(file);

                })(files[i]);

            }

            console.log(arr);

        }


    });
```

The final idea is convert to string `JSON.stringify(arr)` and then parse in php `json_decode($_POST['arr'])`.

Of course this is not working because `JSON.stringify(arr)` gets empty.

Comment: you need to learn how asynchronous code works, I guess

Comment: AS Jaromanda hints already, you have a timing problem here: you can see what is happening, when you put your `console.log()` into the `fr.onload()` function. The array is gradually being built up. Your current `console.log` is currently fired far too early. You could try and bundle your asynchronous requests into a `when()` / `then()` construct (look under "promises").

Comment: If you are going to send it to the server, why do you send all these images as text ? You could simply send it as MultiPart (directly from your blobs), and **if you really need** a b64 version, then do the conversion server-side.

Comment: hey guys, noted, will take a deep look into this your advices... they answer below helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following simple solution works for you? I placed your `console.log()` and your ajax call into the `fr.onload()` method but fire it only, after your results array has been filled up with all values:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filesToUpload = document.getElementById("myFile");
        var files = filesToUpload.files;
        var fd = new FormData();
        var arr = [];
        if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
            for (var i=0; i< files.length; i++){
                (function(file) {
                    var name = file.name;
                    var fr = new FileReader();  
                    fr.onload = function () {
                            arr.push(fr.result);

                            if(arr.length==files.length) {
                              console.log(arr);
                              // place your ajax call here!
                            }
                        }
                       fr.readAsDataURL(file);
                })(files[i]);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: hey mate, this works perfectly, thanks for taking the time.